# Front-fill Null values in a dataframe separated by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill NAs using the most recent data and have it apply to groups.

This is my dataframe

```
pet    id     weight (lbs)
dog    1      30
dog    2      23
dog    3      NaN
cat    4      10
dog    5      NaN
cat    6      NaN
dog    7      39
cat    8      18
hippo  9      138
```

This is what I want the output to be

```
pet    id     weight (lbs)
dog    1      30
dog    2      23
dog    3      23
cat    4      10
dog    5      23
cat    6      10
dog    7      39
cat    8      18
hippo  9      138
```

This is the code for reproducing the dataframe-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pets':['dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'hippo'],
                   'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8],
                   'Weight':[30, 23, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, 39, 10, 138]})
```

In other words, I want to fill in NaNs with the most recent non-null value grouped by pet and order by id. This is the code I tried to use: `dataframe.sort_values(by = 'id').groupby('pet').fillna(method = 'ffill')`

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I ran the code I mentioned and it looks like it worked fine. But, now my 'pet' column is gone. In other words, it filled in the data the right way, but it looks like it deleted the column I grouped on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you have is, pandas GroupBy Object doesn't have sort_values method.

So,first group the dataframe by `pet`, then apply a function which does forward-fill on each group by sorting the dataframe on id.

The reamaining part of `sort_index`, and `reset_index` is there just to get the resulting dataframe in the initial order of pet, and id columns.

```py
out = (df.groupby(['pet'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('id').ffill())
        .sort_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(0, drop=True)
         )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> out
     pet  id  weight (lbs)
0    dog   1          30.0
1    dog   2          23.0
2    dog   3          23.0
3    cat   4          10.0
4    dog   5          23.0
5    cat   6          10.0
6    dog   7          39.0
7    cat   8          18.0
8  hippo   9         138.0
```

Comment: Thanks, so what does reset index do? Is that making sure that the grouping column is still there in the output

Comment: You can try running the code step by step to see how the result appears after each step. first step is grouping, after that `apply`, after that `sort_index`, and after that `rest_index`

Comment: WHY NOT `df.groupby('pet').ffill()`?

Comment: @ansev, OP wants FFILL based on the value of last maximum id

Comment: what is the problem? if we first order the entire dataframe by id when creating the groups they will always be ordered... ordering them for each group is inefficient, check my solution @ThePyGuy

Comment: @Cauder you only need keep all columns, not apply

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by keep all columns, not apply

Comment: the problem is if you use `df.sort_values('id').groupby('pet').ffill()` pet columns is deleted, but you don't need sort by group and you can keep the original order using`assign` or  `.join`.Here assign is more elegant than join' @Cauder

Comment: We can first sort the dataframe and then We can use GroupBy.ffill . In this way we avoid to use apply, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code @Cauder